# Distributing Private apps through Android Management API

Tags: android, mdm, device-owner, android-management-api

I am using Android Management API for setting up kiosk mode. I was able to create an enterprise, enroll a couple of devices, install the apps available in store and control it via policies. It works just fine.

Now I want to publish my app to Play Store as private app (Managed Google Play) and I want it to be available for the devices enrolled to this enterprise only. I have created an organisation, created a policy, and ensured the app is limited to managed google play only, and assigned the organisation to the app. Now the app is published but I cannot able to make it as kiosk mode. It is not visible to enterprise. Even though my enterprise owner and store owner is same account.

I am not sure what else I need to do to make it available for enterprise. I don't want to involve in EMM process since I need this app for few devices for personal purpose.

I have googled a lot but no progress.

Please let me know how to make it available for enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, as we do this at my workplace (A private kiosk application).

It sounds like you've done this already, but make sure the "Managed Google Play" section is completed under "Pricing and Distribution" for your private app in the Google play console.

[image: Google play settings]

For kiosk mode, you need ensure your device is enrolled with [DEVICE_OWNER](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#managementmode) management mode.

Lastly, you need to configure a policy for kiosks [as described in the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk-mode)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

After assigning the app to the organisation, the admin for the enterprise needs to approve the app before it can be distributed to users of that enterprise.
You can go directly to the url for the app (*https://play.google.com/work/apps/details?id=your.apps.package.name*) or search for the app on *https://play.google.com/work* or in the Managed Google Play iFrame and click “Approve”.